# What is the meaning for key icon in Eclipse debug view

Tags: eclipse, debugging

In the picture shown below, there is a key icon under Thread main stack 
trace. What does it mean?

[image: there is a key icon under Thread main stack trace]

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the Thread currently owns the monitor lock on the object shown (the Hashtable with id 221). So `Thread.holdsLock` would return true for that object.